# Having really strange z-index issue with IE7

Tags: css, position, z-index, internet-explorer-7

I have been staring at this for hours and read dozens of posts discussing z-index quirks in IE7 and I can't seem to shake this bug. Maybe has to do with the fact Ive been staring at this code for going on 10 hours now :)

The bug is very clear if you open up the below address in IE7. When the page loads, hover over the menu items on the main nav and you will notice that the dropdowns are forced behind the header slideshow images. I have tried seemingly everything, but of course there is a solution out there somewhere...

Im planning on disabling the site for IE6 with a popup box prompting the user to consider stepping into this decade, but for IE7 I want it to work.

http://demo.curotec.net/bridge/

Any help would be awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for IE7 only

.homeslider.topslideshowwrapper{position:relative; z-index:-1;}